# My sh script always run after entrypoint DOCKERFILE

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker-compose, dockerfile, mariadb

I tried to set up a wordpress solution (installing by myself and not using an official image). I have one container with apache, php and mariadb-client (to interrogate mariadb-server from another container)

I have another container with mariadb on it.

I use wp-cli to configure wordpress website but when i build my docker image, I can't execute the command (inside sh file) which is

```
wp core config --allow-root --dbname=$MYSQL_DATABASE --dbuser=$MYSQL_USER --dbpass=$MYSQL_PASSWORD --dbhost=172.20.0.2 --dbprefix=wp --path=/var/www/html/wordpress
```

because my mariadb container isn't up.

So I tried to run this script with entrypoint parameters and when I do my `docker-compose up`, my script is played and I have the message:

```
apache-php_SDV | Success: Generated 'wp-config.php' file.

apache-php_SDV | Error: The 'wp-config.php' file already exists.
```

My script is played every second, I tried to use CMD before and it doesn't work, it's like CMD wasn't run

I have the same result if I want to put CMD after ENTRYPOINT, I can run my script only when both containers are up.

I also tried to use `command` on my `docker-compose.yml` but not helpful. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve myself, it could be useful, i kill PID 1 who run my first script and i run another script who start apache and take PID 1 to the container, there is the code :

````
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit

case "$1" in
    sh|bash)
        set -- "$@"
    ;;
    *)
        set -- apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND "$@"
    ;;
esac

exec "$@" ```
````